# Not....but only, or not....but

Tags: conjunctions

"It is not metaphorical, but only literal."

In the sentence above, am I allowed to use "but"? It sounds fine, in my opinion, without "but", but I am a foreigner and thus very inept when it comes to legitimacy of sentences. Do I have to use "but", or is it okay to leave it out?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "It is not metaphorical, but only literal" is valid, but you can go ahead to leave "but" out.

Saying "It is not [adj], but only [adj]" is implying that the noun that you're talking about (it) is only describable in only one adjective. Saying "It is not [adj], only [adj]" will imply the same thing.

Comment: @H_H If you find my answer helpful, please click the check mark next to my answer. Thanks!